# Merge [angular-material2] into [angular-material]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just noticed that we have two identical [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/) tags on Stack Overflow

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-material/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-material2/info

Both of them correspond to the same thing.

So I believe that [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2) could be merged into [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material)

Comment: [angular-material2] should go away for no other reason that it states the "current version" is `5.1.0` [sic, original in code formatting for no reason] and requires Angular 5, which was 9 versions ago...

Comment: related: [Rename \[angular2-directives\] to \[angular-directives\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418981/rename-angular2-directives-to-angular-directives) and [Merge \[angular2-template\] into \[angular-template\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418980/merge-angular2-template-into-angular-template)

Comment: From what I can tell, I believe the [angular-material2] tag was introduced when the Angular Material framework was at its ~2.0.0 beta days, while the [angular-material] tag was previously used for the [(now EOL)](https://goo.gle/angularjs-end-of-life) AngularJS Material framework.