# Merge [angular2-template] into [angular-template]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just noticed that we have two identical [Angular-related](https://angular.io/) tags on Stack Overflow

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-template/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular2-template/info

Both of them correspond to the same thing.

So I believe that [angular2-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-template) could be merged into [angular-template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-template)

Comment: The excerpt for [[tag:angular2-template]] says "*This tag is specific to angular version 2.x and above*" - is that irrelevant? Is it still the same as [[tag:angular-template]]?

Comment: @VLAZ the thing is that angular term refers to angular v2+ (currently v14), so it is all just angular and all the same. However if we refer to old angular v1.x we call that angularjs. So `angular-* === angular2-*`, in that particular case `angular2-template` === `angular-template`

Comment: Then the question is how was [angular-template] used? If it was tagged on Angular.js questions, then there needs to be some retagging done, as well. I just checked and there is a tag [[tag:angularjs-templates]] (yes, plural) which is probably the correct one for version 1. I suspect some [angular-template] might need to be moved over to there.

Comment: @VLAZ There is a small amount of questions tagged with both [angular-template] [angularjs] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-template+angularjs in that case if question targeted with both [angularjs] and  [angular-template] the [angular-template] could be changed to  [angularjs-template]