# Rename [angular2-directives] to [angular-directives]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I just noticed that there is an [Angular-relaged](https://angular.io/) tag on Stack Overflow called [angular2-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-directives)

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular2-directives/info

I believe that [angular2-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular2-directives) should be renamed into [angular-directives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directives)

Comment: Maybe combine all angular-* tag requests in one question?

Comment: I'm not well versed in Angular but aren't there basically Angular 1 (Angular.js) and *the rest* Angular 2+ (no .js)? If so, could these tags refer to different directives: for 1 and for 2+? Or is there no actual distinction?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes you right about the way angular vs angularjs distinct from each other. Every question currently market with [angular2-directives] refer to angular (v2+). I  checked there is no [angular-directives] tag here on SO, so it is save to just rename.

Comment: @SurajRao I just saw some old posts here that generalizing that particular issue but seems there was no action taken on that one.